# How to consistently handle timers' delegate executions and user (Form buttons) actions

Tags: c#, timer, .net-4.5

My app contains a pipeline of producers/consumers:

```
-> producer -> workers/producers -> worker -> (timer) ->
\<-----------------------------------------------------/
```

I need the whole work to restart every let's say 30 seconds. I'm using a timer (`System.Timers.Timer`) started when the worker at the bottom of the pipeline completes his work, the timer's delegate signal the waiting producer at the head of the pipeline (I'm using `Monitor` for wait/signal).

This is working, but the user should also be able to stop the whole process and restart it.
My problem is that I cant find a decent way to handle the following situation:

The system is waiting on the timer while the user press the stop button followed soon after by the restart button. To stop the system i must wake it up first (doing the work the timer would have done X second later, can't afford to wait). The various threads die gracefully but the timer is still alive. At restart, thread are resurrected and begin working again. If the timerd decide to execute the delegate now, well it's a problem.

I know i can do `timer.Stop()` but on MSDN it says:

> The event-handling method might run on one thread at the same time
>   that another thread calls the Stop method or sets the Enabled property
>   to false. This might result in the Elapsed event being raised after
>   the timer is stopped.

It also provide an exemple to solve the problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop.aspx but to me it looks a bit too low-level and complicated and involves some kind of sleep/retry loop that makes me thing i'm tring to achive my goal in the wrong way.

Is there a better way to designe the whole thing that allows the pipeline to be restarted every X seconds and doesn't make it impossible to handle a user's stop/restart commands? Maybe not using timers, i really don't know...

Comment: What if you use a form timer, so you know the button presses and the timer ticks always occur in the same thread?

Comment: Also have you handled the additional race condition where the user presses Stop just as your worker is calling `timer.Start()`.

Comment: Or presses Restart while it's still in the process of stopping.

Comment: @DaxFohl yes i've handled those races. The System.Windows.Forms.Timer looks interesting, but the documentation says that it's for single thread applications, it has to be created/accessed on the gui thread, i can create it on the main thread but totally need to start the countdown in the worker and that is not possible am i right?

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the link, if using `System.Timers.Timer` is the best way to do what i described then yes this is a duplicate. If not I would be happy to accept an answer that propose another way. :)